# How To Select User Selected Checkbox If Several With Same Name php

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I want to make it so the select boxes user selects stays selected encase validation fails later in my form the rest of the form works perfect but I cant seem to figure how to do this for select boxes without changing all the names can someone please help I have created this which contains just my form checkboxes and the action I will be doing later on so you can see what I require

```
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<div id="desert_l">
           <label for="hnumber"><div class="bookerror"></div>Desert Choice </label>
          </div>
<div id="desert_f">
  <table width="275">
              <tr>
                <td width="113">
                <label>
<input type="checkbox" name="desgroup[]" value="Vanila Cheesecake"<?php if (isset($dessgroup) && ($dessgroup == "Vanila Cheesecake"))
 {
    echo ' checked="checked""';
  }
 ?>  />

                  Vanilla Cheesecake</label></td>
                <td width="94"><input type="checkbox" name="desgroup[]" value="Carrot Cake"<?php if (isset($dessgroup) && ($dessgroup == "Carrot Cake"))
 {
    echo ' checked="checked""';
  }
 ?> />
Carrot Cake</td>
                <td width="52"><input type="checkbox" name="desgroup[]" value="Jelly"<?php if (isset($dessgroup) && ($dessgroup == "Jelly"))
 {
    echo ' checked="checked""';
  }
 ?> />
Jelly</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="desgroup[]" value="Fruit Cheesecake"<?php if (isset($dessgroup) && ($dessgroup == "Fruit Cheesecake"))
 {
    echo ' checked="checked""';
  }
 ?> >
                  Fruit Cheesecake</label></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="desgroup[]" value="Fruit Flan"<?php if (isset($dessgroup) && ($dessgroup == "Fruit Flan"))
 {
    echo ' checked="checked""';
  }
 ?> />
Fruit Flan</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>

              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="desgroup[]" value="Fruit Platter"<?php if (isset($dessgroup) && ($dessgroup == "Fruit Platter"))
 {
    echo ' checked="checked""';
  }
 ?> />
Fruit Platter</label></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="desgroup[]" value="Chocolate Cake"<?php if (isset($dessgroup) && ($dessgroup == "Chocolate Cake"))
 {
    echo ' checked="checked""';
  }
 ?>/>
Chocolate Cake</td>
           <td>&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
  </table>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
  <p><span class="bookerror">
<?php
$dessgroup = $_POST['desgroup'] ;
if (isset ($_POST['submit']))
{
  if (isset ($dessgroup)) 
  {
     echo "<h2>Desert Choice</h2>";

  // Show Deserts Selected
    for($i=0; $i < count($dessgroup); $i++)
    {
    echo $dessgroup[$i]."</br>";
    }}
   else 
   {
       echo "You Must Select At Least 1 Desert" ;
   }

}
    ?> 
  </span></p>
  <p>Please Choose The Number Specified In Your Menu Choice<br />
</p>
  </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: You can use [**sessions**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) for this, then just use a conditional statement and echo it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
<input type="checkbox" name="desgroup[]" value="Vanila Cheesecake"<?php if (isset($dessgroup) && ($dessgroup == "Vanila Cheesecake"))
 {
    echo ' checked="checked""';
  }
 ?>  />
```

try

```
<input type="checkbox" name="desgroup[]" value="Vanila Cheesecake"<?php if (isset($_POST['desgroup']) && is_array($_POST['desgroup']) && in_array("Vanila Cheesecake", $_POST['desgroup']))
 {
    echo ' checked="checked""';
  }
 ?>  />
```

It would save you a lot of typing though if you would use arrays consequently.

```
$arr = array('possible value 1', 'possible value 2');
foreach ($arr as $val) {
    ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="desgroup[]" value="<?php echo $val; ?>"<?php if (isset($_POST['desgroup']) && is_array($_POST['desgroup']) && in_array($val, $_POST['desgroup']))
     {
        echo ' checked="checked""';
      }
     ?>  />
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Thankyou I done it using the 2nd method then using this to echo the output afterwards

if (isset ($dessgroup)) {
     
      foreach ($dessgroup as $deserts)
     {
     echo $deserts, ',  '; 
     }
     
     }

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="desgroup[]" value="Vanila Cheesecake" <?php echo ((isset($dessgroup) && ($dessgroup == "Vanila Cheesecake")))?'checked="checked"':''; ?> />
```